# How to return only named groups with preg_match or preg_match_all?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Example:

```
$string = "This is some text written on 2010-07-18.";
preg_match('|(?<date>\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)|i', $string, $arr_result);
print_r($arr_result);
```

Returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2010-07-18
    [date] => 2010-07-18
    [1] => 2010-07-18
)
```

But I want it to be:

```
Array
(
    [date] => 2010-07-18
)
```

In PHP's PDO object there is an option that is filtering results from database by removing these duplicate numbered values : [`PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php). But I haven't seen similar modifier for the PCRE functions in PHP yet.

Comment: You can use [T-Regx](http://t-regx.com) and use `namedGroups()` method.

Comment: Of course, the case-insensitive modifier is pointless because digits do not have upper/lower case variations.

Comment: In case anyone comes here looking for an answer with the `n` pattern modifier... it is not suitable for this task.  https://3v4l.org/qBX2Z  The `n` modifier will exclude capture groups which are not named, but it does not exclude the indexed matches from the match results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think you can make `preg_*` do it, but you can do it with a simple loop. But I don't see why those elements pose a problem.

Comment: In small arrays this not pose a problem but in very big with lots of patterns there might be problems with high memory needs.

Second, it looks cleaner that way, and there would be (with this non existent modifier) one line of code less, so less possibility of an error.

Comment: Quite the opposite: because this can't be done by PCRE, you'd have to add more code, where there could be more problems.

Comment: I meant the additional elements in the array.

Comment: What the opposite, if this modifier i ask for would exist then that extra line wouldn't be needed, it would be even better if it would be a global modifier that would set preferences of all pcre functions setting mode for output arrays

I repeat it: it was done in PDO object, what it can't be done in pcre ?

Comment: as you said: PDO object-based, pcre is still function-based. They'll possibly change it some time later, as the language evolves.

Comment: You could also use [T-Regx](https://t-regx.github.io) library which has `namedGroups()` method :D

Answer (score 20):

> How to return only named groups with preg_match or preg_match_all?

This is currently (PHP7) not possible. 
You will always get a mixed type array, containing numeric and named keys.

Lets quote the PHP manual (http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php):

> This subpattern will then be indexed in the matches array by its
>   normal numeric position and also by name.

---

To solve the problem the following code snippets might help:

**1. filter the array by using an is_string check on the array key** (for PHP5.6+)

```
$array_filtered = array_filter($array, "is_string", ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

**2. foreach over the elements and unset if array key is_int()** (all PHP versions)

```
/**
 * @param array $array
 * @return array
 */
function dropNumericKeys(array $array)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_int($key)) {
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Its a simple PHP function named `dropNumericKeys()`. Its for the post-processing of an matches array after a `preg_match*()` run using named groups for matching. The functions accepts an `$array`. It iterates the array and removes/unsets all keys with integer type, leaving keys with string type untouched. Finally, the function returns the array with "now" only named keys.

Note: The function is for PHP downward compatiblity. It works on all versions. The `array_filter` solution relies on the constant `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY`, which is only available on PHP5.6+. See http://php.net/manual/de/array.constants.php#constant.array-filter-use-key

Comment: why define a function if you have a solution as simple as #1

Comment: The function is for PHP downward compatiblity. It works on all versions. The `array_filter` solution relies on the constant `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY`, which is only available on PHP5.6+. See http://php.net/manual/de/array.constants.php#constant.array-filter-use-key

Comment: 3rd option... use `array_intersect_key`... with a list of the names

Answer (score 14):

[`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) does not have any flag or option that it only returns named matches (yet). So what you want is not directly possible. However you can remove all items with non-fitting keys from your matches array and then you get what you're looking for:

```
$matches = array_intersect_key($matches, array_flip(array('name', 'likes')));
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8174845/3889189) that hakre posted above, I use this snippet to get just the named parameters:

```
$subject = "This is some text written on 2010-07-18.";
$pattern = '|(?<date>\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)|i';
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
echo '<pre>Before Diff: ', print_r($matches, 1), '</pre>';
$matches = array_diff_key($matches[0], range(0, count($matches[0])));
echo '<pre>After Diff: ', print_r($matches, 1), '</pre>';
```

...which produces this:

```
Before Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2010-07-18
            [date] => 2010-07-18
            [1] => 2010-07-18
        )

)
After Array
(
    [date] => 2010-07-18
)
```

Answer (score 2):

It also possible to unset all numeric indexes before return:

```
foreach (range(0, floor(count($arr_result) / 2)) as $index) {
    unset($arr_result[$index]);
}
```

Comment: When you want to floor the result of division, just call `intdiv()`.

Answer (score 1):

I read in your post that these are possible overloads of future memory etc ...
In this case, why no't can be solved with an **unset()**:

```
$string = "This is some text written on 2010-07-18.";
preg_match('|(?<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})|i', $string, $arr_result);
$date = array("date" => $arr_result['date']);
unset($arr_result, $string);//delete array and string preg_match origen

print_r($date);
//or create a new:
//  $arr_result = $date;
//print_r($arr_result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [T-Regx](https://t-regx.github.io) and go with `group()` or `namedGroups()` which only returns named capturing groups.

```
<?php
$subject = "This is some text written on 2010-07-18.";

pattern('(?<date>\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)', 'i')->match($subject)->first(function ($match) {

    $date = $match->get('date'); 
    // 2010-07-18

    $groups = $match->namedGroups(); 
    // [
    //   'date' => '2010-07-18'
    // ]   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I use some of introduced codes and this is the final code works on php 5.6+:

```
$re = '/\d+\r\n(?<start>[\d\0:]+),\d+\s--\>\s(?<end>[\d\0:]+),.*\r\nHOME.*\r\nGPS\((?<x>[\d\.]+),(?<y>[\d\.]+),(?<d>[\d\.]+)\)\sBAROMETER\:(?<h>[\d\.]+)/';

$str= file_get_contents($srtFile);
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
echo '<pre>';
$filtered=array_map(function ($d){
     return $array_filtered = array_filter($d, "is_string", ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
    },$matches);
var_dump($filtered);
```

if you are interested what it does it read position data from a str file that DJI drones generate while recording video.

Comment: `$array_filtered =` is useless/unused because the data is only returned in the callback.  This answer is only duplicating the advice found in the accepted answer.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
$string = "This is some text written on 2010-07-18."; 
preg_match('|(?<date>\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)|i',$string,$arr_result);
echo $arr_result['date'];
```

Comment: no, that is wrong, I meant a modifier to automatically delete keys that are numbers, it's not that easy on multibranched array that preg_match_all might produce