# How can I get only named captures from preg_match?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, pcre

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to force preg_match preg_match_all to return only named parts of regex expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275963/how-to-force-preg-match-preg-match-all-to-return-only-named-parts-of-regex-expre)

I have this snippet:

```
$string = 'Hello, my name is Linda. I like Pepsi.';
$regex = '/name is (?<name>[^.]+)\..*?like (?<likes>[^.]+)/';

preg_match($regex, $string, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => name is Linda. I like Pepsi
    [name] => Linda
    [1] => Linda
    [likes] => Pepsi
    [2] => Pepsi
)
```

How can I get it to return just:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Linda
    [likes] => Pepsi
)
```

Without resorting to filtering of the result array:

```
foreach ($matches as $key => $value) {
    if (is_int($key)) 
        unset($matches[$key]);
}
```

Comment: You can use [T-Regx](https://t-regx.github.io) library, and use `namedGroups()` method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

preg_match will always return the numeric indexes regardless of named capturing groups

Answer (score 2):

```
return array(
    'name' => $matches['name'],
    'likes' => $matches['likes'],
);
```

Some kind of filter, sure.

Comment: `foreach($matches as $k => $v) {
                    if(is_int($k)) {
                        unset($matches[$k]);
                    }
                }` to strip numeric keys and keep only the named ones.

Comment: Nowadays (php 5.6+) `$matches = array_filter($matches, 'is_string', ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);` is a simpler way to achieve the same. Apply 'is_string' as a filter on the keys.