# regex riddle. want results: 'onetwothree', 'onetwo', 'twothree' but NOT 'two'. Positive lookahead maybe?. For currency extraction

Tags: php, regex, currency, regex-lookarounds

confused with some basic regex logic. Using simple example:

```
(one)(two)(three)
```

I want regex to catch:

```
onetwothree
onetwo
   twothree
```

but NOT

```
   two
```

and catching in groups (one)(two)(three).

I know I can use positive lookahead on 'two' so that it is only preceded by 'one':

```
(one)?((?<=one)two)(three)?
```

but then I cannot get the 'twothree' result

The real world need is for currency:

```
group one:   [$¥£€₹]
group two:   ((?:\d{1,10}[,. ])*\d{1,10})
group three: ( ?(?:[$¥£€₹]|AUD|USD|GBP|EURO?S?\b))
```

so I want to get these results:

```
$20,000 AUD
$20,000
 20,000 AUD
```

but NOT

```
 20,000
```

help appreciated!

PS need matches in groups (one)(two)(three) or (one)(two) or (two)(three).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a pure regex response:

```
(ONE)?TWO(?(1)(THREE)?|THREE)
```

Using conditionals, you can check to see if the first group matched, and if it did, then you can make the last group mandatory.

```
(ONE)?TWO(?(1)(THREE)?|THREE)
^     ^  ^^^^^   ^       ^
1     2    3     4       5

1: Try to match ONE. If you can't find it, no big deal.
2: You absolutely must have TWO.
3: If the first group DID match (ONE), then...
4: ... Use the first result
5: Otherwise use the second result
```

With this, we just make the first result be optional, so if we match ONE, then THREE is optional. If we miss ONE, then THREE is mandatory.

```
ONE
TWO
THREE
ONETWO       // Matches! (e.g: $20,000)
ONETHREE
TWOTHREE     // Matches! (e.g: 20,000 AUD)
ONETWOTHREE  // Matches! (e.g: $20,000 AUD)
```

[Try it online!](https://regex101.com/r/HUfyTt/1)

[Read more about conditional regex patterns in PHP here.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.conditional.php)

Comment: thats great!! thanks.
I modified it a bit to get the capture groups capturing.
`(ONE)?(TWO)((?(1)(?:THREE)?|THREE))` and updated your regex101 [here](https://regex101.com/r/HUfyTt/2)

Comment: what does "pure regex" mean?

Comment: @eis - It just means I'm not using a mix of Regex and PHP to get a solution. It's just Regex, so it should also work for other people (even if they're using Python, Java, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I would just discard any lookaheads/lookbehinds and just define all cases separately and then combine them. It is more rebust, easier to reason with and understand and more effective.

So do

(^(groupone)(grouptwo)$)|(^(groupone)(grouptwo)(groupthree)$)|(^(grouptwo)(groupthree)$)

For example:

```
$groupone    = '[$¥£€₹]';
$grouptwo    = '(?:\d{1,10}[,. ])*\d{1,10}';
$groupthree  = ' ?([$¥£€₹]|AUD|USD|GBP|EURO)';
$caseone     = "^($groupone)($grouptwo)$";
$casetwo     = "^($groupone)($grouptwo)($groupthree)$";
$casethree   = "^($grouptwo)($groupthree)$";
$allcases    = "/($caseone)|($casetwo)|($casethree)/";

preg_match($allcases, '20,000 AUD', $matches);
print_r($matches); // matches, preg_match returns 1

preg_match($allcases, '$20,000', $matches);
print_r($matches); // matches, preg_match returns 1

preg_match($allcases, '$20,000 AUD', $matches);
print_r($matches); // matches, preg_match returns 1

preg_match($allcases, '20,000', $matches);
print_r($matches); // empty, preg_match returns 0
```

To make results look nicer (skip empty results, duplicates, extra whitespaces etc) I'd additionally use a cleanup function:

```
<?php
$groupone    = '[$¥£€₹]';
$grouptwo    = '(?:\d{1,10}[,. ])*\d{1,10}';
$groupthree  = ' ?([$¥£€₹]|AUD|USD|GBP|EURO)';
$caseone     = "^($groupone)($grouptwo)$";
$casetwo     = "^($grouptwo)($groupthree)$";
$casethree   = "^($groupone)($grouptwo)($groupthree)$";
$allcases    = "/($caseone)|($casetwo)|($casethree)/";

function cleanup($arr) {
  # trim trailing, ending whitespace
  $newarr = array_map('trim', $arr);
  # remove empty values
  $newarr = array_filter($newarr, function($value) { return $value !== ''; });
  # remove duplicates
  $newarr = array_unique($newarr);
  # we're only interested about the values
  return array_values($newarr);
}

preg_match($allcases, '20,000 AUD', $matches);
print_r(cleanup($matches));

preg_match($allcases, '$20,000', $matches);
print_r(cleanup($matches));

preg_match($allcases, '$20,000 AUD', $matches);
print_r(cleanup($matches));

preg_match($allcases, '20,000', $matches);
print_r(cleanup($matches));
```

Which would get you results like

```
Array
(
    [0] => 20,000 AUD
    [1] => 20,000
    [2] => AUD
)
Array
(
    [0] => $20,000
    [1] => $
    [2] => 20,000
)
Array
(
    [0] => $20,000 AUD
    [1] => $
    [2] => 20,000
    [3] => AUD
)
Array
(
)
```

Edit: if you want the groups to be the same, you can use named groups like

```
$groupone    = '(?<currencyprefix>[$¥£€₹])';
$grouptwo    = '((?:\d{1,10}[,. ])*\d{1,10})';
$groupthree  = ' ?(?<currencypostfix>([$¥£€₹]|AUD|USD|GBP|EURO))';
$caseone     = "^$groupone$grouptwo$";
$casetwo     = "^$grouptwo$groupthree$";
$casethree   = "^$groupone$grouptwo$groupthree$";
$allcases    = "/(?J)($caseone)|($casetwo)|($casethree)/";

function cleanup($arr) {
  $currencyprefix = isset($arr['currencyprefix']) ? $arr['currencyprefix'] : null;
  $currencypostfix = isset($arr['currencypostfix']) ? $arr['currencypostfix'] :null;

  return array($currencyprefix, $currencypostfix);
}

if (preg_match($allcases, '20,000 AUD', $matches))
  print_r(cleanup($matches));

if (preg_match($allcases, '$20,000', $matches))
  print_r(cleanup($matches));

if (preg_match($allcases, '$20,000 AUD', $matches))
  print_r(cleanup($matches));

if (preg_match($allcases, '20,000', $matches))
  print_r(cleanup($matches));
```

Which would get you

```
Array
(
    [0] =>
    [1] => AUD
)
Array
(
    [0] => $
    [1] =>
)
Array
(
    [0] => $
    [1] => AUD
)
```

Or, use named keys in end results too:

```
$groupone    = '(?<currencyprefix>[$¥£€₹])';
$grouptwo    = '((?:\d{1,10}[,. ])*\d{1,10})';
$groupthree  = ' ?(?<currencypostfix>([$¥£€₹]|AUD|USD|GBP|EURO))';
$caseone     = "^$groupone$grouptwo$";
$casetwo     = "^$grouptwo$groupthree$";
$casethree   = "^$groupone$grouptwo$groupthree$";
$allcases    = "/(?J)($caseone)|($casetwo)|($casethree)/";

function cleanup($arr) {
  $newarr = array_filter($arr, function($var){ return !empty($var); });
  return array_filter($newarr, "is_string", ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
}

if (preg_match($allcases, '20,000 AUD', $matches))
  print_r(cleanup($matches));

if (preg_match($allcases, '$20,000', $matches))
  print_r(cleanup($matches));

if (preg_match($allcases, '$20,000 AUD', $matches))
  print_r(cleanup($matches));

if (preg_match($allcases, '20,000', $matches))
  print_r(cleanup($matches));
```

With results:

```
Array
(
    [currencypostfix] => AUD
)
Array
(
    [currencyprefix] => $
)
Array
(
    [currencyprefix] => $
    [currencypostfix] => AUD
)
```

Comment: ahh thanks!! another method. Yes I see how its clean without empy key values, however , in your example above, [2] => AUD in the first array...and in the 3rd. its [3] => AUD - I would need AUD consistent with the same extracted group. 

I wanted "AUD" to go into its own group consistent along results

Comment: @BenedictHarris ok, added to my answer

Answer (score 0):

You could use an alternation with an optional group.

```
\bonetwo(?:three)?|twothree\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oeV5EE/1)

An example with named capture groups and the J flag to allow duplicate subpattern names:

```
(?P<symbol>[$¥£€₹])(?P<amount>\d{1,10}(?:[.,]\d{1,10})?)(?:\h+(?P<currency>AUD|USD|GBP|EURO?S?)\b)?\b|(?P<amount>\d{1,10}(?:[.,]\d{1,10})?)\h+(?P<currency>AUD|USD|GBP|EURO?S?)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cU11op/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/W1aed)

```
$strings = [
    "$20,000 AUD",
    "$20,000",
    "20,000 AUD",
    "$",
    "20,000",
    "AUD"
];
$re = '/(?P<symbol>[$¥£€₹])(?P<amount>\d{1,10}(?:[.,]\d{1,10})?)(?:\h+(?P<currency>AUD|USD|GBP|EURO?S?)\b)?\b|(?P<amount>\d{1,10}(?:[.,]\d{1,10})?)\h+(?P<currency>AUD|USD|GBP|EURO?S?)\b/J';
foreach ($strings as $s) {
    $m = preg_match($re, $s, $matches);
    if ($m) {
        print_r($matches);
    }
}
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => $20,000 AUD
    [symbol] => $
    [1] => $
    [amount] => 20,000
    [2] => 20,000
    [currency] => AUD
    [3] => AUD
)
Array
(
    [0] => $20,000
    [symbol] => $
    [1] => $
    [amount] => 20,000
    [2] => 20,000
)
Array
(
    [0] => 20,000 AUD
    [symbol] => 
    [1] => 
    [amount] => 20,000
    [2] => 
    [currency] => AUD
    [3] => 
    [4] => 20,000
    [5] => AUD
)
```

Or [see an example](https://3v4l.org/npgqH) without the [numerical keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275963/how-to-return-only-named-groups-with-preg-match-or-preg-match-all) which will give

```
Array
(
    [symbol] => $
    [amount] => 20,000
    [currency] => AUD
)
Array
(
    [symbol] => $
    [amount] => 20,000
)
Array
(
    [symbol] => 
    [amount] => 20,000
    [currency] => AUD
)
```